# PayPal REST API: trying to activate a billing plan, but getting "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized"

Tags: rest, api, paypal, unauthorized

I am building an EC site, where my customers can pay through PayPal API. Now, I am learning how it works, using Sandbox; referring to this page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-plans/

I have succeeded the prerequisites, i.e., having created a PayPal app,
gotten an access token, and made an API call. And then, I have succeeded making a billing plan, copying-and-pasting the sample command on the page, just replacing the Access Token.

Now, I want to activate the billing plan, but couldn't have succeeded.

The command used is, once again, copied-and-pasted from the page, as below.

```
curl -v -k -X PATCH https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-7DC96732KA7763723UOPKETA/ \
  -H 'X-PAYPAL-OAUTH-CONTEXT: {"consumer":{"accountNumber":1181198218909172527,"merchantId":"5KW8F2FXKX5HA"},"merchant":{"accountNumber":1659371090107732880,"merchantId":"2J6QB8YJQSJRJ"},"apiCaller":{"clientId":"AdtlNBDhgmQWi2xk6edqJVKklPFyDWxtyKuXuyVT-OgdnnKpAVsbKHgvqHHP","appId":"APP-6DV794347V142302B","payerId":"2J6QB8YJQSJRJ","accountNumber":"1659371090107732880"},"scopes":["https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.*","https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/futurepayments","openid"]}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '[{
  "op": "replace",
  "path": "/",
  "value": {
    "state": "ACTIVE"
  }
}]'
```

First, as instructed, I just replaced the Plan ID "P-7DC96732KA7763723UOPKETA" with mine, provided in the previous response for creating the plan.

```
*   Trying 173.0.82.78...
* Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.78) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: api.sandbox.paypal.com
* Server certificate: Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
> PATCH /v1/payments/billing-plans/P-8AX21799EN516221GJMBOECA/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> X-PAYPAL-OAUTH-CONTEXT: {"consumer":{"accountNumber":1181198218909172527,"merchantId":"5KW8F2FXKX5HA"},"merchant":{"accountNumber":1659371090107732880,"merchantId":"2J6QB8YJQSJRJ"},"apiCaller":{"clientId":"AdtlNBDhgmQWi2xk6edqJVKklPFyDWxtyKuXuyVT-OgdnnKpAVsbKHgvqHHP","appId":"APP-6DV794347V142302B","payerId":"2J6QB8YJQSJRJ","accountNumber":"1659371090107732880"},"scopes":["ttps://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.*","ttps://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/futurepayments","openid"]}
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 78
>
* upload completely sent off: 78 out of 78 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Fri, 17 Feb 2017 12:18:47 GMT
< Server: Apache
< paypal-debug-id: c46e304b4bb46
< Paypal-Debug-Id: c46e304b4bb46
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D669689432%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3D; Expires=Fri, 17 Feb 2017 12:48:47 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
<
* Closing connection 0
```

And I tried with some other parameter replacements, like the Client ID, but no luck.

Do I need to replace other parameters?
Or, have I done something wrong?

Comment: Do you used the correct access token?

Comment: Thanks for your post. Yes, according to the record I kept, I used the correct access token, which I had gotten from the prerequisite process; I suppose that I wouldn't have succeeded to make the billing plan, otherwise. By the way, the problem I have now--activating the billing plan--does not require the access code, regarding the command I need to put in the command line, as shown in my original post. Please correct me if wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: This was solved; please see my own answer. You are right about the access token; the successful command I used includes the access token. Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: Its my pleasure mate ! Have fun coding there.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED.

[On this page, I found simpler and more straightforward command](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/#plan_update)

and made up below:

```
curl -v -X PATCH https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/<Plan ID>/ \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <Access Token>" \
-d '[
  {
  "path":"/",
  "value":{"state":"ACTIVE"},
  "op":"replace"}
]'
```

Got the response as below:

```
*   Trying 173.0.82.78...
* Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.78) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: api.sandbox.paypal.com
* Server certificate: Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
> GET /v1/payments/billing-plans/<Plan ID> HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json
> Authorization: Bearer <Access Token>
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 19 Feb 2017 11:36:50 GMT
< Server: Apache
< paypal-debug-id: 3ca31778e271e
< Content-Language: *
< Paypal-Debug-Id: 3ca31778e271e
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D1384360280%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3D; Expires=Sun, 19 Feb 2017 12:06:52 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
< Vary: Authorization
< Content-Length: 1391
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: application/json
< 
* Closing connection 0
{"id":"<Plan ID>","state":"ACTIVE","name":"Sample Plan",
...
"rel":"self","method":"GET"}]}
```

Got HTTP 200 and the state "ACTIVE".

Thanks for your trying to help, many thanks!